# live stream testing within c#

Tags: c#, video-streaming

Is it possible within c# to test if a live stream is active?
e.g. I want to test if if a stream like

```
http://<server>/live.ts
```

is broadcasting audio/video or both?
If possible without using ffprobe

Comment: there are ffmpeg wrappers for c#, since ffprobe is part of ffmpeg, it could be possible to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks I managed to resolve it using
MediaToolKit - available on NuGet

https://github.com/AydinAdn/MediaToolKit